# How to inject Javascript file using Imacros from Macro script

Tags: javascript, parsing, xpath, imacros

Hi I am using Imacros for creating web based automation script for js parsing.

I have one JS file "nikhil.js".

Now I need to call this file from my Imacros macro. I need to run this file from mynikhil.iim macros file.

**Browser : ie11**

**Os: windows 8.1**

**Imacros version: latest (trial)**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its is Veryspecific to the Tool Imacro and is outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that your file called "nikhil.js" is placed in the default datasource folder. So the "mynikhil.iim" macro may look like:

```
SET myFolder {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}
SET myScript "nikhil.js"
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=file:///{{myFolder}}/{{myScript}}

SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=* ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
TAB CLOSE
URL GOTO=javascript:{{!EXTRACT}}
```